# Is there a way I can simplify this?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm using a Laravel Eloquent Collection filter. I'm pretty sure this can be simplified but I'm not sure exactly. I am using all the variables after this chunk of code but I'd like to refactor so it's nicer.

```
    $cards = new Collection($data);

    $whiteBlueBlackRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Black","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});

    $whiteBlueBlackRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Black","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlueBlackGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Black","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlueRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlackRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Black","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $blueBlackRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Black","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});

    $whiteBlueBlack = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Black"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlueRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlueGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlackRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Black","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlackGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Black","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $blueBlackRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Black","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $blueBlackGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Black","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $blueRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $blackRedGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Black","Red","Green"]') { return true; }});

    $whiteBlue = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Blue"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteBlack = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Black"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $whiteGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $blueBlack = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Black"]') { return true; }});
    $blueRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $blueGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $blackRed = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Black","Red"]') { return true; }});
    $blackGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Black","Green"]') { return true; }});
    $redGreen = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Red","Green"]') { return true; }});

    $white = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["White"]') { return true; }});
    $blue = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Blue"]') { return true; }});
    $black = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Black"]') { return true; }});
    $red = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Red"]') { return true; }});
    $green = $cards->filter(function($card) { if ($card->colors == '["Green"]') { return true; }});
```

Comment: I would say if there is a better way to do this, we need to see what you are attempting to do with these variables later on in the code.  Certainly you shouldn't have to make so many variables.

Comment: I don't know if it'd be appropriate to ask for that. It's hundreds of lines of code. I was thinking I could get feedback for chunks and update accordingly.

Comment: So in general it feels like you're trying to make variables for every possible combination of MTG card colors - perhaps you should be generating an array and then using a combinatorics function to generate all of the possible combinations, then generating array keys dynamically based on those combinations.

Comment: @rotaercz I've added an expanded portion to my answer that does the combinatorics bit I mentioned. It shortens the code significantly and changes it to use an array rather than tons of variables.

Comment: @Amber: You play MTG? :) Yeah, I'm making a fan site in my spare time for fun and to learn Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could factor out the filtering a bit:

```
function getCards($cards, $colors) {
    return $cards->filter(function($card) use ($colors) {
        if ($card->colors == $colors) { return true; }
    });
}

$whiteBlueBlackRedGreen = getCards($cards, '["White","Blue","Black","Red","Green"]');
// and so on...
```

That would avoid a lot of repetitive typing and make the code easier to read.

---

Going deeper down the rabbit hole...

```
$cards = new Collection($data);

function getCards($cards, $colors) {
    return $cards->filter(function($card) use ($colors) {
        if ($card->colors == $colors) { return true; }
    });
}

$colors = array("White", "Blue", "Black", "Red", "Green");
$coloredCards = array();
foreach($colors as $color) {
    foreach($coloredCards as $existingCombo => $existingCards) {
        $newKey = $existingCombo . "-" . $color;
        $coloredCards[$newKey] = getCards($cards, json_encode(explode("-", $newKey)));
    }
    $coloredCards[$color] = getCards($cards, '["' . $color . '"]');
}
```

I haven't actually tested this, but it should get you an array with keys like `$coloredCards['White-Blue-Black']` that contains what your variables would have.

Edit: I've tested a version that doesn't actually call getCards to make sure it's the proper set of combinations - you can see the test here: http://ideone.com/Uk6H5x

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that right now. :) I'd like to see if there are other suggestions though. Upthumb for you sir!

Comment: After I updated as you suggested I'm getting an error: Undefined variable: colors, on this line: if ($card->colors == $colors) { return true; } Not sure why though?

Comment: Oh, because `$colors` is defined in the outer function, not the inner one. I've updated it with the proper `use` invocation that should solve the issue for PHP 5.3+

Comment: Oh man, that second part is really helpful. I was hoping to get some insight like this.